# How can I stream text, poetry in this case on a line by line basis?

Tags: html, stream

I would like to stream text, poetry in this case on a line by line basis across a simple html page or by running a script.  The lines would appear on the page, but with a 5-6 second time delay.  I may want to show one or two lines at a time.  I've been able to create an SWF type file that lets you do this manually.  But it does not work or show on an iPad.  I would like it to flow if possible

You can see what I did here at this URL.

http://www.saintjulianpress.com/storm-shadow.html

I would like emulate what is seen on the PoemFlow site, but on a web page on my own site.

Here is the PoemFlow site: http://poemflow.com/

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Are you looking for Javascript to do this? Or an SWF solution?

Answer (score 0):

It would be pretty easy to do this with javascript using the timing events like setTimeout(). You could use jQuery to have the text fadeIn and fadeOut or animate in.

Comment: Dear Dazzler - could you provide a link or sample code on how to do this please.  Something I could add the text to please?  - Thanks, Ron

Answer (score 0):

Since you made a video for it and are having trouble displaying it on the ipad because of flash, I suggest that you use the HTML5 video tag. It isn't flash, so it will work on an ipad. Here is a link http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp

There are some ipad specific tutorials around the web about how to do it if you have any trouble.